# Spark Streaming RDD with a list of previous values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, real-time, spark-streaming

I'm not really sure how to do this with Spark Streaming, it is really giving me a headache.
I have an input stream of some users, for example User1, User2, etc with some parameters, which are not important for now. Then I do some processing on those parameters and get a current state of the user, which can be, for example A, B, C, like this:

```
   (User1, A)
   (User2, B)
   (User3, B)
```

In some other point in the near future I get a new set of events, which might be like this:

```
   (User1, C)
   (User2, B)
   (User3, A)
```

Until now it is no problem. The tricky part is how to generate a RDD which could have a structure like this, for all of the events in the last X seconds:

```
   (User1, (A, C))
   (User2, (B, B))
   (User3, (B, A))
```

If it is not obvious, I would like to generate a list of the previous states the user was in in the last X seconds. Is there a way of achieving this with Spark Streaming? Until now I would usually do this with Esper, but Spark Streaming still looks something useful for the job.

I'm not limiting myself to a tuple in the examples above, the parenthesis are only for explaining the process.

Edit:

Here is a code example I have so far.

```
val userZone = positions.map(position =>
      if (
        position.latitude > 45.445 &&
          position.latitude < 45.48 &&
          position.longitude > 9.14 &&
          position.longitude < 9.24)
        (position, "center")
      else (position, "out")

    val groupedByZones = userZone.groupByKeyAndWindow(Seconds(120))
    groupedByZones.foreachRDD(rdd =>
    {
      rdd.foreach(record => {
        println(record._1.userid + ":" + record._2)
      })
    })
```

So my desired output should be something like:

```
U1: (center, out, center)
U2 (center,center,out)...
```

But for now I'm only getting separate values like:

```
U1 : center
U1 : out
U1 : center
```

I hope I'm being clear.

Comment: You can try with updateStateByKey which can have your previous status and do any calculation with the upcoming events. http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/streaming-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few ways to do this in Spark Streaming. The simplest that comes to mind is groupByKeyAndWindow (which you can see in http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.PairDStreamFunctions ).

Comment: Hi. That doesn't really cut it. There must be some additional step which I can't figure out, I've updated my question.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question :) The problem is that your keys are not identical, in your first map instead of using position as the key you should use position.userid . For groupByKeyAndWindow. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ouh, fiddlesticks... How could I miss that :/ . Thank you :) . Sorry to stretch your patience but is there any rule about the ordering of the grouped RDDs? Will they be sorted in order of appearance or is it random, just curious.

Comment: Order within a DStream is kind of complicated and probably better suited to another question (slash I'd have to go read some more code to double check as well).

Comment: Thanks, no need to do that :)

Comment: @Holden  does the value still get reported for say top N over all time?